# How do you achieve a “clock wipe”/ radial wipe effect

Tags: android, android-animation

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios), but I want to do it in Android. Basically I want to achieve the radial wipe on any image, either through XML or through code.

I am currently trying to do this by using multiple images and swapping them after interval. It looks horrible though. Is there any other way to do it through animation.

Comment: Read about Paint.setShader() and about BitmapShader class

Comment: Once you have your shader working, just call Canvas.drawArc in onDraw method of your custom View

Comment: and this is a working custom View implementation: http://pastebin.com/XfzMF7Yp