# Animation Corresponding to UITimer

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

I am coding a game in Swift where the player has to make a move within a second, or else time runs out and he/she loses. How can I make an animation that runs every second, resembling the one in the top of Snapchat stories, where it is a filled in circle that slowly "wipes" away in a circular motion like a windshield wiper? Is it just a second-long GIF that I loop every second? Is there a way to do this with native UIKit graphics?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a "clock wipe" animation. You can do that by adding a mask layer to your image and animating it using Core Animation.

I wrote a SO post on this very subject: 
[How do you achieve a "clock wipe"/ radial wipe effect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios)