# How to Change Color of UIBezierPath Stroke Whilst Animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I was wondering if it was possible to change the color of a UIBezierPath strokeColor while its animating. For instance, if it goes past a certain angle like 45 deg, it changes from green to orange, and if it goes past 66 deg it goes from orange to red.

Comment: you can use GradualLayer.

Comment: What's GradualLayer?

Comment: @Faisai Syed https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cagradientlayer

Comment: That should be `CAGradientLayer`, not `GradualLayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else suggested using a "gradual" (gradient) layer. If you can create a gradient that meets your needs then that would work.

You could do just about anything you want by creating an image that contains the colors you want, and then installing a shape layer as a mask layer to that image's layer, and animating changes to the path installed in the shape layer.

I've used a technique like that to create various sorts of "wipe" transitions that reveal an image. See the thread below for info and working code showing how to create a "Clock wipe", which is almost exactly what you need:

[How do you achieve a "clock wipe"/ radial wipe effect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios)