# Animating CAShapeLayer path smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to make a Gauge UIView to mimic the following image as close as possible
[image: Goal]

```
    func gradientBezierPath(percent: CGFloat) ->  UIBezierPath {
        // vary this to move the start of the arc
        let startAngle = CGFloat(180).toRadians()//-CGFloat.pi / 2  // This corresponds to 12 0'clock
        // vary this to vary the size of the segment, in per cent
        let proportion = CGFloat(50 * percent)
        let centre = CGPoint (x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
        let radius = self.frame.size.height/4//self.frame.size.width / (CGFloat(130).toRadians())
        let arc = CGFloat.pi * 2 * proportion / 100 // i.e. the proportion of a full circle

        // Start a mutable path
        let cPath = UIBezierPath()
        // Move to the centre
        cPath.move(to: centre)
        // Draw a line to the circumference
        cPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: centre.x + radius * cos(startAngle), y: centre.y + radius * sin(startAngle)))
        // NOW draw the arc
        cPath.addArc(withCenter: centre, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: arc + startAngle, clockwise: true)
        // Line back to the centre, where we started (or the stroke doesn't work, though the fill does)
        cPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: centre.x, y: centre.y))
        
        return cPath
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
//        let endAngle = percent == 1.0 ? 0 : (percent * 180) + 180
        
        path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                            radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                            startAngle: CGFloat(180).toRadians(),
                            endAngle: CGFloat(0).toRadians(),
                            clockwise: true)
        
        percentPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2),
                                   radius: self.frame.size.height/4,
                                   startAngle: CGFloat(180).toRadians(),
                                   endAngle: CGFloat(0).toRadians(),
                                   clockwise: true)
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = self.path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 110 / 255, green: 78 / 255, blue: 165 / 255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        percentLayer.path = self.percentPath.cgPath
        percentLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 255 / 255, green: 93 / 255, blue: 41 / 255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        percentLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        percentLayer.lineWidth = 8.0
//        percentLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(percent)
        percentLayer.lineCap = .round
        self.layer.addSublayer(percentLayer)
        
        // n.b. as @MartinR points out `cPath.close()` does the same!

        // circle shape
        circleShape.path = gradientBezierPath(percent: 1.0).cgPath//cPath.cgPath
        circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
        
        gradient.frame = frame
        gradient.mask = circleShape
        gradient.type = .radial
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 255 / 255, green: 93 / 255, blue: 41 / 255, alpha: 0.0).cgColor,
                           UIColor(red: 255 / 255, green: 93 / 255, blue: 41 / 255, alpha: 0.0).cgColor,
                           UIColor(red: 255 / 255, green: 93 / 255, blue: 41 / 255, alpha: 0.4).cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0, 0.35, 1]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.49, y: 0.55) // increase Y adds more orange from top to bottom
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.98, y: 1) // increase x pushes orange out more to edges
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

        //myTextLayer.string = "\(Int(percent * 100))"
        myTextLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        myTextLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        myTextLayer.fontSize = 85.0
        myTextLayer.frame = CGRect(x: (self.frame.size.width / 2) - (self.frame.size.width/8), y: (self.frame.size.height / 2) - self.frame.size.height/8, width: 120, height: 120)
        self.layer.addSublayer(myTextLayer)
        
    }
```

This produces the following in a playground which is pretty close to what i'm aiming for:
[image]

The problem comes when trying to animate the change in the gauge value. I can animate the `percentLayer` pretty easy with modifying `strokeEnd`, but animating the `circleShape.path` for the gradient results in some non-smooth animations if there's a large change in the percent value of the gauge. Here's the function i use to animate both layers (it's called on a timer every 2 seconds right now to simulate gauge value changes).

```
    func randomPercent() {
        let random = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...1.0)
        
        // Animate the percent layer
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = percentLayer.strokeEnd
        animation.toValue = random
        animation.duration = 1.5
        percentLayer.strokeEnd = random
        percentLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        
        // Animate the gradient layer
        let newShapePath = gradientBezierPath(percent: random)
        let gradientAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        gradientAnimation.duration = 1.5
        gradientAnimation.toValue = newShapePath
        gradientAnimation.fromValue = circleShape.path
        circleShape.path = newShapePath.cgPath
        self.circleShape.add(gradientAnimation, forKey: nil)
        
        myTextLayer.string = "\(Int(random * 100))"
    }
```

[image]

Notice how when the animation is done with small changes in the value, the animation looks good. However when there's a large change the gradient animation doesn't look natural at all. Any ideas on how to improve this? Or maybe is it possible to animate a different keyPath for better performance? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I like the look of your gauge. The gradient fill looks really good. Not sure I like the rounded end-caps though. It causes the gradient to not line up with the tip of the rounded end-cap, and looks a little odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the Bezier path `addArc()` function to animate an arc and change the arc distance.

The problem is control points. In order for an animation to work smoothly, the starting and ending shape must have the same number and type of control points. Under the covers, the UIBezierPath (and CGPath) objects create arcs approximating a circle by combining Bezier curves (I don't remember if it uses Quadratic or Cubic Bezier curves.) The entire circle is made up of multiple connected Bezier curves ("Bezier" the mathematical spline function, not UIBeizerPath, which is a UIKit function that creates shapes that can include Bezier paths.) I seem to remember a Bezier approximation of a circle is made up of 4 linked cubic Bezier curves. (See [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338311/205185) for a discussion of what that looks like, if you're interested.)

Here is my understanding of how it works. (I might have the details wrong, but it illustrates the problem in any case.) As you move from <= 1/4 of a full circle to > 1/4 of a full circle, the arc function will use first 1 cubic Bezier section, then 2. At the transition from <= 1/2 of a circle to > 1/2 of a circle, it will shift to 3 Bezier curves, and at the transition from <= 3/4 of a circle to > 3/4 of a circle, it will switch to 4 Bezier curves.

### The solution:

You are on the right track with using strokeEnd. Always create your shape as the full circle, and set strokeEnd to something less than 1. That will give you a part of a circle, but in a way that you **can** animate smoothly. (You can animate strokeStart as well.)

I've animated circles just like you describe using CAShapeLayer and strokeEnd (It was a number of years ago, so it was in Objective-C.) I wrote [**an article here on OS on using the approach to animate a mask on a UIImageView and create a "clock wipe" animation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios). If you have an image of your full shaded circle you could use that exact approach here. (You should be able to add a mask layer to any UIView's content layer or other layer, and animate that layer as in my clock wipe demo. Let me know if you need help deciphering the Objective-C.

Here is the sample clock wipe animation I created:

[image: Clock wipe animation]

Note that you can use this effect to mask *any* layer, not just an image view.

### EDIT: I posted an update to my clock wipe animation question and answer with a Swift version of the project.

You can get to the new repo directly at https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockWipeSwift.

For your application I would set up the parts of your gauge that you need to animate as a composite of layers. You'd then attach a CAShapeLayer based mask layer to that composite layer and add a circle arc path to that shape layer and animate the strokeEnd as shown in my sample project. My clock wipe animation reveals the image like the sweep of a clock hand from the center of the layer. In your case you'd center the arc on the bottom center of your layer, and only use a half-circle arc in your shape layer. Using a mask that way would give you a sharp-edged crop to your composited layer. you'd lose the round end caps on your red arc. To fix that you'd have to animate the red arc as it's own shape layer (using strokeEnd) and animate the gradient fill's arc strokeEnd separately.

Comment: Note that I just posted an update to my thread on clock wipe animations that includes a Swift version of the clock wipe animation. You can find the project here: https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockWipeSwift